# Which Class Loader should I use?

Tags: java, class, loader

JNDI use Thread context class loader.
Because its guts are implemented by bootstrap classes in rt.jar
but core JNDI classes may load JNDI providers implemented by independent vendors and potentially deployed in the application's -classpath.
Father class loader can not use child class loader to load class.

Question :
As we all known parent delegation model is a important feature,
Why not using system class loader everywhere? Child class loader can use father class loader to load class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure I understand your question.

Especially in JEE runtime environments the Context Classloader of your current thread is you best choice.

Essentially it all boils down to the hierachy (which may even be inverted or use something like OSGI somewhere) and the missing knowledge on where exatly in the classloader hiearchy you class is actually located.

Multiple classloaders in general are a necessity, because it is sometimes needed to have different versions of the same class, p.ex. in different applications running on the same JVM.